# Form authentication cookie vulnerability

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis-7

I have a question regarding `Form authentication` cookie vulnerability. In JavaScript we can use document.cookie to access form authentication cookie value (assuming it is not httponly). This value is encrypted. I have read in many blogs that if someone get's this value our security is breached. My question is how can he(attacker) breach it(the credentials inside the cookie) since the form authentication encryption method uses machine key to encrypt that cookie, so to decrypt it, the same machine key would be needed? Isn't that so? Can you clarify me on this that how that cookie value is vulnerable since the attacker should have my machine key with him only then he can decrypts it? Am I right here?

Comment: You might wanna read up on it here. However, if I'm not mistaken some form of countermeasure was realeased by MS. http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/09/14/aspnet-security-hack.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can he(attacker) breach it(the credentials inside the cookie) since the form authentication encryption

He doesn't have to decrypt the encrypted cookie. He could just use the encrypted value of the cookie and become you.

The server does the encryption, so it doesn't know that the browser giving it the cookie was who the cookie was originally issued to.

Using an extension like [Modify This Cookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg) (or anything else that achieves that functionality) would allow me to set my cookie to your encrypted value if I were able to obtain it.

Ironically, [the very same question](http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/08/is-stack-overflow-secure-kind-of.html) was asked about StackOverflow. Have a look at Troy's post for further information.

Comment: MAN! You are right. I think he can create a dummy cookie at his client and can set the value (hijacked one) and can send it to server? Is this correct?

Comment: @RockySingh yep. That's why HTTPS is important, even beyond the initial authentication step. HTTPS encrypts cookies over-the-wire as well.

Comment: @RockySingh I added a link to a blog that should explain it in-depth a little more.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done, don't know how much it actually helps, but I've never seen any breaches (although there are some 100 attempts made) is to pair the cookie with an IP-address, which means that I look up if the call comes from the same IP-address as the previous call, if not, it resets the cookie and you'll have to log in again. This isn't exactly viable for all sites, but in my case it was more important to add some measures of security rather than allowing for mobility.

This approach is probably nicely suceptible for MITM attacks, but you can never protect yourself against all eventualities except if you have a monster budget and no restrictions regarding performance and accessibility.

Comment: Requiring a user to stay at the same IP address introduces the risk of denying access to legitimate users.  Users may change IP address within a session for a variety of reasons:
* Plug or unplug Ethernet cable and switch to/from Wi-Fi
* Change Wi-Fi hotspots or cell towers by moving around
* Connect/disconnect from VPN (changes default route)
* Dynamic NAT using a pool of IP addresses
* Load-balanced or distributed proxies

Matching on only part of the IP address can lessen the effect...but also leaves the door open for someone at the same coffeeshop to hijack the connection.

Comment: Well, the application of IP address verification is mainly deployed in solutions that require that level of security. It all comes down to what you're trying to protect I guess.